# Jenkins stop build on unit test first failure

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui

I have a maven job running in jenkins. This maven project runs soap project which contains testcases. The pom.xml of this maven project is configured as

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>src.main.resources</groupId>
<artifactId>soapui-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Maven 2 soapUI Sample</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
         <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
    <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <runnerType>OSS</runnerType>
                <projectFile>Dev-Offline-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/tatunka-reports</outputFolder>
                <testSuite>SmokeTestSuite</testSuite>
                <testSuiteProperties>
                    <properties>
                        <property>serviceEndpoint=${serviceEndpoint}</property>
                    </properties>
                </testSuiteProperties>
                <skipAfterFailureCount>1</skipAfterFailureCount> 
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <configuration>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                </configuration>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                    <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And in jenkins *goal and options* is given as

```
test -DserviceEndpoint=http://localhost:8080/DAMService/solutionid -DskipTests=true
```

What I want is the jenkins to stop running other testcases if any testcase fails. 
For example, i have 9 testcases and 4th testcase fails then remaining 5 testcases should not be executed.

I tried to give

```
<skipAfterFailureCount>1</skipAfterFailureCount>
```

but no result.
And even tried giving 
`-DskipTests=true` option as build arguement.
And also tried with goal `verify`. But could not achieve to stop the running of testcases.
Please, let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: not familiar with the plugin but a brief search does not show me anything config key named `skipAfterFailureCount`.  And, it is the behavior of the soap ui plugin instead of jenkin to provide such kind of behavior (skip the rest of tests if any test fail).  If they don't provide it (for which I believe is the case after a quick check), there is not much you can do

Comment: @AdrianShum thanks for the reply and your time. Tried hard searching for the solution. Keeping finger crossed.. i hope somebody have an idea on achieving this.

Comment: I strongly doubt if it is something provided by the soapui plugin (or even in soapui).  If it is not, I think you can never get the solution by waiting.  Consider raising an issue to the plugin / soapui, or fix it by yourself  :)

Comment: Thanks @AdrianShum :) exploring other options. Great suggestion! I will raise the issue and try fixing the issue by myself, although it will take awful lot of time.

Comment: a good starting point is to see if you can achieve what you need in plain SoapUI.  If so, it is quite possibly that it will be a simple change in the plugin to configure SoapUI accordingly.  If it is something not available in SoapUI, then.... wish you good luck :P

Comment: @AmirMalik were you able to find solution to this problem? am facing similar issue but am not using maven. i want to check if its possible via jenkins itself.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>`under plugin configuration and try

Comment: tried your suggestion but it is still running other test cases. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh. Then change it to false.`<testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>`